# ECL Copy data to metadata Stub schema

Tags: web8.5, ecl

ECL components has an stub schema that can have two types of metadata:
- Metadata that comes from the external system and it's requested in real time every time that the component is open.
- Metadata that you can store in SDL Web.

My question is, when a user selects an asset and try to link to a component, a component stub is created in SDL Web. At this moment, could you copy information of the metadata that comes from the external system to the metadata stored in SDL Web?

Comment: Since you know your ECL stub schema (the one that will be used to create component stub) you should try with EventSystem on Component Save. And you should came up with solution how to sync metadata after it is changed in external system.

Comment: Thank you, Stefan. If you put your comment as response I can check it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you know your ECL stub schema (the one that will be used to create component stub) you should try with EventSystem on Component Save. And you should came up with solution how to sync metadata after it is changed in external system.